# No docker-quickstart found on mac

Tags: macos, docker, cloudera

I am trying out Cloudera on Docker. The command to launch Cloudera is `docker run --privileged=true --hostname=quickstart.cloudera -t -i ${HASH} /usr/bin/docker-quickstart`. However, I do not have `/usr/bin/docker-quickstart` at all. I am sure that I followed the default steps to install Docker on my MacBook. Does anyone know where to fetch this binary executable? Or is there a better way to run Cloudera on Docker?

[Update] Using Cloudera on virtual machine is a preferred way and saves time for setting up configuration.

Answer (score 0):

/usr/bin/docker-quickstart is an executable script that is available in the docker image.

Following directions from https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-6-x/topics/quickstart_docker_container.html I did the following:

```
% docker pull cloudera/quickstart:latest
latest: Pulling from cloudera/quickstart
1d00652ce734: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:f91bee4cdfa2c92ea3652929a22f729d4d13fc838b00f120e630f91c941acb63
Status: Downloaded newer image for cloudera/quickstart:latest
% docker images
REPOSITORY            TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
cloudera/quickstart   latest              4239cd2958c6        14 months ago       6.34 GB
% docker run --hostname=quickstart.cloudera --privileged=true -t -i cloudera/quickstart /usr/bin/docker-quickstart
Starting mysqld:                                           [  OK  ]

if [ "$1" == "start" ] ; then
    if [ "${EC2}" == 'true' ]; then
...
Using CATALINA_PID:    /var/run/solr/solr.pid
Started Impala Catalog Server (catalogd) :                 [  OK  ]
Started Impala Server (impalad):                           [  OK  ]
[root@quickstart /]#
```

This started the cluster.  Then in the shell, I verified the shell script exists.

```
[root@quickstart /]# cd /usr/bin
[root@quickstart bin]# file docker-quickstart
docker-quickstart: a /usr/bin/env bash script text executable
[root@quickstart bin]#
```